# Use siri to fluently add item to non-default list

Tags: ios, shortcut, automation, siri

Is there a way to get siri to learn that when I say

"Hey Siri, add vacuuming to my chores"

I want her to add a new item "vacuuming" to my reminders list called "chores".

I'm aware that you can say "Add a reminder for vacuuming to the chores list" But that's not as fluent. I'm hoping there's a way to teach her to do certain things based on a user-specified pattern. I looked at the shortcuts app, but there's no obvious way to get it to work with Siri. I found an item to prompt and add some text to chores list. But no way to get siri to fill in that text that I could see.